# windows app stuck on stage publishing

Tags: cordova, windows

I searched for find out the time for update of windows app on store but i
     could not find out the solution on that. i have uploaded my new package of
     windows phone application on store before approx 5 hours back. i can see 
    status of app is showing waiting for release . that means it is on publishing 
    stage from four hours approx. how much time it can take.
  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my application approved in 25 minutes, but have also waited for 5 days.

Don't worry it won't take 5 days, just give it some time and you'll get the approved / rejected email.

Comment: Hi Dimitris thanks for you reply . i can see my app on app store. issue is happening with me is that when i am installing this app from store then after download 30% it get crashed. can you tell me what i am missing . my old package was like (Windows Phone 8.1 packages "CordovaApp.Phone_0.0.1.3_AnyCPU.appxbundle") that package i created through windows app certification kit. but after update my vs2013  i directly got package that is on store currently (Windows Phone 8.0 packages "CordovaAppProj_Release_AnyCPU.xap") . m i missing some thing . i am totally new in this .

Comment: during download and install in phone it show There is a problem completing your request. Try again later.
Inquiring minds may find this error code helpful: 80070002
[Close]

Comment: @manojkumarSrivastaw If you can see your app on store then you're done. any errors that occur like the 80070002 are from Microsoft's side. I have seen it many times, it'll be fixed and everything's gonna be okay!

Comment: @manojkumarSrivastaw How long was your app in "publishing" stage ?

Comment: @John actually i have updated it in morning 10am and it had reflected on next morning so 20 hours approx..

Comment: Mine also took over 24 hours in the publishing stage, and I didn't even receive an email indicating it was visible on the store. The app webpages on the microsoft site also took a couple of days to appear.